# How do you pass a variable limit into a Backbone.Firebase.Collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebase, backfire

The firebase documentation here (https://github.com/firebase/backfire#backbonefirebasecollection) mentions that you can apply a limit to a Backbone.Firebase.Collection:

```
var Messages = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
  firebase: new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com").limit(10)
});
```

I would like to make that limit a variable - so I could sometimes show 10 records from the collection and sometimes 100 (as an example).

Can anyone recommend the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Your best bet in this case would be simply create a new collection with the new limit. It's not easy to dynamically change limits once they've been applied to a Firebase reference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Anant - I think I will instead just not use the backbone integration to retrieve the records - appreciate the feedback though!

Comment: I'd love to see this feature implemented in Firebase. You basically can't do infinite pagination without unnecessarily re-requesting and  redrawing elements that haven't really changed -- unless there's a way to assign a new firebase reference to an existing collection, that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase now supports query limits, using limitToFirst or limitToLast

The following code would get the first 2 records.

`var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/");
ref.orderByChild("height").limitToFirst(2).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});`

More info in the docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limittofirst.html